# Failed to register android device in WSO2 EMM. Showing error Incorrect user Infromation

Tags: wso2-iot

Also need help about is it necessary to mention domain name in LAN?

OS is CentOS 7
Firewall is enabled and 9443 and 9763 port numbers are allowed.

WSO2 agent is default agent and trying to register android mobile with
server : 10.0.26.145:9763
Domain : [blank]
userID : test1
Password : SVt5ln

Answer (score 0):

Domain name is needed only if you are enrolling the device to a tenant. If you are enrolling a device which a user is in super tenant then you do not need to set the domain name. Also try setting the port to 8280 and allow it via the firewall.